# Dotnet docker issue with ports

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, kestrel

I have a dotnet application and use this ksetrel appsettings.json file, When I run the application, everything is worked on port 8082.

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://localhost:8082"
    }
  }
},
```

I have created the Dockerfile like this for my app:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8082

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

<COPY ...> # copy my files and projects

RUN dotnet restore "proj/proj.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/proj"
RUN dotnet build "proj.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "proj.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "proj.dll"]
```

and finally here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  bs:
    image: bs
    ports:
      - "8091:8082"
```

But when I build my image with `docker build -t bs .` command and run ths with `docker compose up -d` command, I cant see anything in port 8091 of my machine and when I enter the http://localhost:8091/swagger in my browser, it shows the `This site can’t be reached` message.

and here is the logs for the container:

```
2023/07/29 09:47:07 [WRN] Overriding address(es) '"http://+:80"'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
2023/07/29 09:47:07 [INF] Now listening on: "http://localhost:8082"
2023/07/29 09:47:07 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023/07/29 09:47:07 [INF] Hosting environment: "Production"
2023/07/29 09:47:07 [INF] Content root path: "/app/"
2023/07/29 09:52:40 [INF] Application is shutting down...
2023/07/29 09:54:57 [WRN] Overriding address(es) '"http://+:80"'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
2023/07/29 09:54:57 [INF] Now listening on: "http://localhost:8082"
2023/07/29 09:54:57 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023/07/29 09:54:57 [INF] Hosting environment: "Production"
2023/07/29 09:54:57 [INF] Content root path: "/app/"
```

Comment: what does `docker ps` show?

Comment: @Turing85
59dd4fd415cb   bs                   "dotnet …"   4 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:8091->8082/tcp, :::8091->8082/tcp       bs

Comment: Looking at the compose-setup, this all looks correct.

Comment: @Turing85
for all other containers everything is correct!

Comment: check the logs `docker logs <container name or id>`

Comment: Your app running on **Production** mode, check if swagger is enabled only on **Development**.

Comment: @Max swagger is enabled in both modes

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the docker-compose.yml like below. Replace "your project name" with your project name in Visual Studio (or the relative path of the Dockerfile with respect to docker-compose.yml).

```
services:
  bs:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bs
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: <your project name>/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - "8091:8082"
```